# jq: edit a single field while converting to CSV

Tags: json, csv, jq

## Intro

I have researched and tried this for 2 days. I haven't been successful in either finding a similar question or in finding an answer myself.

I have the following JSON payload (from VRA APIs)

```
{ "content": [
 {
  "@type": "CatalogResource",
  "id": "ccc",
  "iconId": "xxx",
  "resourceTypeRef": {
    "id": "Infrastructure.Virtual",
    "label": "Virtual Machine"
 },
  "name": "name01",
  "description": "example01",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "catalogItem": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "label": "xxxxx"
 },
  "requestId": "xxxxx",
  "providerBinding": {
    "bindingId": "xxxx",
    "providerRef": {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "label": "xxxxx"
    }
 },
  "owners": [
    {
      "tenantName": "xxxxx",
      "ref": "xxxxxxxx",
      "type": "USER",
      "value": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "organization": {
    "tenantRef": "xxxx",
    "tenantLabel": "xxxxxxx",
    "subtenantRef": "xxxxxx",
    "subtenantLabel": "xxxxxxxxx"
 },
  "dateCreated": "2015-10-05T08:58:35.133Z",
  "lastUpdated": "2015-12-03T13:23:54.187Z",
  "hasLease": true,
  "lease": {
    "start": "2015-10-05T08:21:31.000Z"
 },
  "leaseForDisplay": null,
  "hasCosts": true,
  "costs": {
    "leaseRate": {
      "type": "moneyTimeRate",
      "cost": {
        "type": "money",
        "currencyCode": "GBP",
        "amount": 99999
      },
      "basis": {
        "type": "timeSpan",
        "unit": "DAYS",
        "amount": 1
      }
    }
 },
  "costToDate": {
    "type": "money",
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "amount": 19181
 },
  "totalCost": null,
  "childResources": [],
  "operations": null,
  "forms": {
    "catalogResourceInfoHidden": true,
    "details": {
      "type": "extension",
      "extensionId": "xxxxxx",
      "extensionPointId": null
    }
  },
  "resourceData": {
    "entries": []
  }
},
{
  "@type": "CatalogResource",
  "id": "ccc",
  "iconId": "xxx",
  "resourceTypeRef": {
    "id": "Infrastructure.Virtual",
    "label": "Virtual Machine"
  },
  "name": "name01",
  "description": "this, is, my, problem",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "catalogItem": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "label": "xxxxx"
  },
  "requestId": "xxxxx",
  "providerBinding": {
    "bindingId": "xxxx",
    "providerRef": {
      "id": "xxxxx",
      "label": "xxxxx"
    }
  },
  "owners": [
    {
      "tenantName": "xxxxx",
      "ref": "xxxxxxxx",
      "type": "USER",
      "value": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "organization": {
    "tenantRef": "xxxx",
    "tenantLabel": "xxxxxxx",
    "subtenantRef": "xxxxxx",
    "subtenantLabel": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "dateCreated": "2015-10-05T08:58:35.133Z",
  "lastUpdated": "2015-12-03T13:23:54.187Z",
  "hasLease": true,
  "lease": {
    "start": "2015-10-05T08:21:31.000Z"
  },
  "leaseForDisplay": null,
  "hasCosts": true,
  "costs": {
    "leaseRate": {
      "type": "moneyTimeRate",
      "cost": {
        "type": "money",
        "currencyCode": "GBP",
        "amount": 99999
      },
      "basis": {
        "type": "timeSpan",
        "unit": "DAYS",
        "amount": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "costToDate": {
    "type": "money",
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    "amount": 19181
  },
  "totalCost": null,
  "childResources": [],
  "operations": null,
  "forms": {
    "catalogResourceInfoHidden": true,
    "details": {
      "type": "extension",
      "extensionId": "xxxxxx",
      "extensionPointId": null
    }
  },
  "resourceData": {
    "entries": []
  }
}
]
}
```

I convert it to CSV as follows:

```
jq --raw-output -r '.content[0] | [.name,.id,.resourceTypeRef.label,.description,.status,.catalogItem.label,.owners[0].value,.dateCreated,.costs.leaseRate.cost.amount,.costToDate.amount] | @csv'
```

## Question

I need to edit the .description field and remove commas when present.

I am looking for a *jq* way to do it; I could do it at shell level using *sed* or *awk* but I would like to know if it's possible using jq within the same command I use to generate the CSV.

Thanks!!

Comment: The jq command doesn't work

Comment: You are right and I apologise. The JSON code was an extract. It is still an extract of the entire JSON returned by the VRA call, but I have modified it now and it should work with the *jq* example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`gsub/2`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#gsub(regex;string),gsub(regex;string;flags)) to perform the replacements using regular expressions. So for the description part, do the replacement.

```
(.description | gsub(","; ""))
```

Comment: it works! I did not have the parenthesis around the entry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, you gotta be careful with the operator precedence. The pipe isn't as high as you might think.